# Switching from LaTeX to XeLaTeX documentation

Tags: xetex

I know this has been asked from time to time but I didn't really found the question I searched.

I'm currently thinking about switching from LaTeX to XeTeX and read about some packages that one shouldn't use it with XeLaTeX and some package one should use with xelatex.

Is there some way to generically (for each package without asking for each package here) check which packages should and shouldn't be used with XeLaTeX?

Comment: did you mean to write xelatex not pdflatex in the title?

Comment: basically the difference is don't use `inputenc` (always use the default UTF-8 encoding) and then probably avoid any font related packages. I say "probably" as the font mechanisms are quite different but some packages  detect xetex and do the right thing for xetex and pdflatex anyway eg `\usepackage{lmodern}` loads 8bit latin modern fonts in pdftex and the latin modern opentype font if used with xetex, but that switch is specific to that package.

Comment: @atticus; I've changed the subject/title to "Switching from LaTeX to XeLaTeX documentation" as you are mentioned about "XeLaTeX" not "PDFLaTeX"

Comment: Switching from "pure" LaTeX, as it were, anyway — have you considered LuaLaTeX? It seems to be under more active development than XeLaTeX.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning/correcting my typo ;)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle hm I also read to replace `babl` with `polyglossia`. Since this is something I wouldn't have thought about, I'm searching for a way to check other packages for XeLaTeX support

Comment: @Ingmar I'm thinking about it, but I think I have to do more research to be able to decide whether I'm going to use XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX

Comment: @atticus I'd stick with babel

Comment: I recently made the switch (finally), and it's been painless. I keep using babel, by the way.

Comment: Hm ok. Seems like this is a controversial topic and one cannot really say replace this package by that one.

Comment: @atticus polyglossia was developed at a time that babel had no active developer and hadn't been adapted to xetex/luatex so didn't really work well with xetex, so you will find lots of older pages saying to use babel with pdftex and polyglossia with xetex but for several years now babel has had a new active maintainer and is actively supported  with xetex and luatex.

Comment: Ah, that's nice to know